# Перевод времени на час назад.

Tags: php, freebsd, сервер

Как перевести время на сервере на час назад?

Или в PHP/

OS FreeBsd

Comment: Так обновления же выпустили за 2-3 недели до этого. Нужно было обновить несколько пакетов.

Comment: @Il Hamitov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Обновление временных зон на freebsd:

```
portsnap fetch && portsnap update
cd /usr/ports/misc/zoneinfo/ && make install clean
tzsetup
ntpdate ru.pool.ntp.org
date
```

Правда, в связи с переходом на новый пакетный менеджер на 9 версии предложено было обновить его, что я и сделал по инструкции.
Ну и, чем ребутать всякие сервисы поочередно, проще будет ребутнуть сам сервер.